# How do you disassemble Solana programs?

Tags: program, build-sbf

Basically, what the title says. Since SBF != eBPF, the eBPF disassemblers don't work. When I try

```
$ solana-ledger-tool program disassemble foo.so
```

it complains about me not having a ledger folder or a genesis.bin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`solana-ledger-tool` requiring a ledger and genesis.bin for that command is a bug; `disassemble` doesn't actually use anything from the ledger. I'll take a look at fixing that soon, but for now, you can do the following to work around this:

```
$ mkdir dummy_ledger
$ touch dummy_ledger/genesis.bin
$ solana-ledger-tool program disassemble foo.so --ledger dummy_ledger
```

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/32770 resolves the issue properly

Answer (score 2):

The Solana CLI comes with a special `dump.sh` shell script which can do it for you:

```
$ ~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/scripts/dump.sh program.so dump.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use binutils:

```
brew install binutils


llvm-objdump \
--demangle \
--print-imm-hex \
-g --full-leading-addr \
--debug-vars --section-headers \
--symbolize-operands \
--source --disassemble foo.so
```